# Getting error for Newman which is having self signed certificates

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

Newman calls are getting failed for the postman calls which has a token in the request header. Postman request with Token in the request is giving response with warning for self signed certificates in postman. Here the postman is able to finish the test whereas Newman scripts are erroring(failing) out.

Reports
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Roles is full access account undefined

```
call newman run %CollectionFile% -e %EnvFile% -g %GolbalFile% -r cli, json --folder=Tok2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
call newman run %CollectionFile% -e %EnvFile% -g %GolbalFile% -r cli, json --folder=Tok2 -k
```

> -k, --insecure Disables SSL verification checks and allows self-signed SSL certificates

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

pass -k or --insecure flag to disable SSL validation

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used -k and also --insecure, but still getting the error.

Comment: please add the new commadn you used

Comment: call newman run %CollectionFile% -e %EnvFile% -g %GolbalFile% -r cli, json --folder=Tok2 -k --insecure   AND      call newman run %CollectionFile% -e %EnvFile% -g %GolbalFile% -r cli, json --folder=Tok2 -k  AND call newman run %CollectionFile% -e %EnvFile% -g %GolbalFile% -r cli, json --folder=Tok2 --insecure....i tried all 3 combinations

Comment: may be enclose all variables with double quotes , see how is the final command is resolved